# What is a second-type-touch for curve?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, curves

Let I have some f: R^2 -> R. And M is a zero-set point of f. Suppose f is infinity differenced and gradient is not 0 forever. If f(x0, y0)=0 how can I define second-type-touch from f_x(x0, y0), f_y(x0, y0), f_xx(x0, y0), f_xy(x0, y0) and f_yy(x0, y0)?

Comment: I need a formula for touch-line

Comment: I'm not not sure what you are seeking exactly, but perhaps it is the Taylor formula? Here is a wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions